# Minimize function with logical arguments

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How can I minimize or maximize a function (even numerically) with logical arguments, taking only 0s and 1s, also with constraints? E.g.

```
NMinimize[{x1 * 24 + x2*51 + x1*x2 *36, 12 x1+36 x2<44}, {x1,x2}]
```

The example of course is stupid one, but question as a matter of principle, when you have many arguments.

Comment: `Min[Pick[Outer[Function[{x1, x2}, x1*24 + x2*51 + x1*x2*36], {0, 1}, {0, 1}], Outer[Function[{x1, x2}, 12 x1 + 36 x2 < 44], {0, 1}, {0, 1}]]]`?

Comment: I need something general, true for many arguments.

Comment: `Min[Pick[Function[{x1, x2}, x1*24 + x2*51 + x1*x2*36] @@@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], Function[{x1, x2}, 12 x1 + 36 x2 < 44] @@@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]]]`. Adjust the second argument of `Tuples[]` as seen fit.

Comment: Great! I was just thinking there should be some special ways for categorial optimization.

Comment: How about the following? `NMinimize[{x1*24 + x2*51 + x1*x2*36, 12 x1 + 36 x2 < 44 && And @@ (0 <= # <= 1 && # \[Element] Integers & /@ {x1, x2})}, {x1, 
  x2}]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use $v^2 = v$ as a constraint. For your example:

```
NMinimize[
    {
    x1*24 + x2*51 + x1*x2*36,
    12 x1+36 x2<44 && x1^2==x1 && x2^2==x2},
    {x1,x2},
    Integers
]
```

> {0., {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0}}

Comment: Alternatively, add constraint `0<=x1<=1` and similar for `x2`. And keep the `Integers` domain specification. Not sure which of these will perform better in general so might want to experiment.